# ReactJS/Typescript Axios Get Cross CORS Supported For HTTP

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, react-hooks

When I do axios http with ReactJS, Typescript, I get **Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP** and errors in other images.

http://localhost:1337/reviews is up.

**HelpCenter.tsx**

```
import React, { FC, constructor, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios, { AxiosResponse, AxiosError } from "axios";

const HelpCenter: FC = () => {

 useEffect(() => {
   axios.get('localhost:1337/reviews/')
   .then((response: AxiosResponse) => {
      console.log(response.data);
  });
});

return ()

}

export default HelpCenter
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you try to add `http://` before `localhost:1337/reviews/` ?

Comment: You should specify full URL address, which begins with `http://` , `https://` etc.

Comment: It is work. Thanks